# HTML5 clearRect dont work

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hello could somebody tell me wath is wrong with my code. When i do the clear rect, it's doesn't work.

I just try to move the ball in the canvas. Actually my ball leave a mark. This kind of line is leave.
[image]

```
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="_js/jquery1.6.js" type="text/jscript"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>    
        <canvas id="dropBall" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
     <script>
         var dropBall = $("#dropBall")[0];
         var dropContext = dropBall.getContext("2d");
dropContext.fillStyle = "green";
         var ballX = 200;
         var ballY = 200;
         function activeBall() {
             dropContext.clearRect(0, 0, dropBall.width, dropBall.height);
             dropContext.arc(ballX, ballY, 10, 2 * Math.PI, 0, true);
             dropContext.fill();

             ballY--;
             ballX++;
             var time = 100;
             setTimeout("activeBall()", time);
         }
         activeBall();
    </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't it be:

```
dropContext.clearRect(ballX,ballY,dropBall.width,dropBall.height);
```

or am I misunderstanding something?

If you do it the other way around, then the only rectangle getting cleared is the square from (0,0) to (width of ball,height of ball).

EDIT: 
It actually might be

```
dropContext.clearRect(ballX-(dropBall.width/2),ballY-(dropBall.height/2),dropBall.width,dropBall.height);
```

If your ball is centered at ballX.

EDIT EDIT:

I fixed it for you:

```
function activeBall() {
         dropContext.clearRect(ballX-(dropBall.width/2),ballY-(dropBall.height/2),dropBall.width,dropBall.height);
         dropContext.beginPath();
         dropContext.arc(ballX, ballY, 10, 2 * Math.PI, 0, true);
         dropContext.fill();

         ballY--;
         ballX++;
         var time = 100;
         setTimeout("activeBall()", time);
     }
```

1. You were clearing a rectangle on the top-left corner of your canvas.
2. You have to call beginPath() and then do all your drawing work. Clearing has to be called outside of beginPath() and fill().

The specific lines are:

```
         dropContext.clearRect(ballX-(dropBall.width/2),ballY-(dropBall.height/2),dropBall.width,dropBall.height);
         dropContext.beginPath();
```

Comment: I made an edit. Try it now.  Can you also screenshot what type of mark it leaves>

Answer (score 0):

Your Document DocType is wrong

For HTML5 try

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

This can cause mis-behavior from some browsers..

some html resources...

http://simon.html5.org/html-elements
http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: Thanks but i dont think my problem is linked with the doctype.